# GCP startup script not running

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, startup

I'm trying to run a startup script on a managed instance group of spot VMs. The instance template is:

```
gcloud compute instance-templates create spot-template \
    --machine-type e2-micro \
    --tags http-server \
    --metadata-from-file=startup-script=/path/to/startup/script.sh \
    --provisioning-model=SPOT \
    --instance-termination-action=STOP
```

The startup script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash -i
sleep 60
yes Y | sudo apt-get update

# Install tmux
yes Y | sudo apt-get install tmux

# Install conda
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b
rm Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh  
~/miniconda3/bin/conda init bash
eval "$(cat ~/.bashrc | tail -n +10)"
source ~/.bashrc

################ GSUTIL ###################
gsutil cp -r gs://my_bucket/spot_vm ~/
###########################################

yes Y | conda create -n test python=3.10

tmux new-session -d 'cd ~/spot_vm; eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"; conda activate test; python spot_test.py'
```

`spot_test.py` script simply writes the current time every minute on a file.

If I manually create a `startup_script.sh` with the above and run it on the VM it works correctly. However when it runs as a startup script, or when I try to simulate it running as a startup script myself with `sudo google_metadata_script_runner startup` it doesn't work, and the log I get from `sudo journalctl -u google-startup-scripts.service -f` is:

```
Aug 28 11:09:43 spot-test-8zvw google_metadata_script_runner[844]: startup-script:
Aug 28 11:09:43 spot-test-8zvw google_metadata_script_runner[844]: startup-script:
Aug 28 11:09:43 spot-test-8zvw google_metadata_script_runner[844]: startup-script: Operation completed over 31 objects/30.3 KiB.
Aug 28 11:09:43 spot-test-8zvw google_metadata_script_runner[844]: startup-script: bash: conda: command not found
Aug 28 11:09:43 spot-test-8zvw google_metadata_script_runner[844]: startup-script exit status 0
Aug 28 11:09:43 spot-test-8zvw google_metadata_script_runner[844]: Finished running startup scripts.
Aug 28 11:09:43 spot-test-8zvw systemd[1]: google-startup-scripts.service: Succeeded.
Aug 28 11:09:43 spot-test-8zvw systemd[1]: google-startup-scripts.service: Unit process 2869 (tmux: server) remains running after unit stopped.
Aug 28 11:09:43 spot-test-8zvw systemd[1]: Finished Google Compute Engine Startup Scripts.
Aug 28 11:09:43 spot-test-8zvw systemd[1]: google-startup-scripts.service: Consumed 21.343s CPU time.
```

What is going on? It looks like the startup script is running in a different place? I can't find the `spot_vm` directory and filed it says it pulled anywhere... Please help!

Comment: Startup scripts do not run as a user. You are using the tilde character `~` which represents the user's home directory. Commands like this will fail `~/miniconda3/bin/conda init bash`. Redesign your script to not reference a user's home directory. Next, starting `tmux` in a startup script will not work.

Comment: Your script run, but fail. Use absolute path instead of relative or binaries in our PATH (use full path for `bash` for instance)

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley absolute paths worked! The next question is, how do I run a python file on a persistent sessions (that will run for days) if I can't use tmux? Ideally I would also like to be able to ssh into that VM and check that everything is running well (with tmux attach)

Comment: Make your Python app into a `service`. Search for articles like this: https://medium.com/codex/setup-a-python-script-as-a-service-through-systemctl-systemd-f0cc55a42267

Comment: @JohnHanley One more thing: how do I redesign the home directory in the proper way? This command still won't work: `/home/user/miniconda3/bin/conda init bash`

Comment: I cannot answer that as I don't know Conda. However, at system startup, you run as a system process and the system is still in the startup phase. Don't do things that require users or home directories. You might be able to configure Conda to install in the `root` user home directory, but I am not sure. I would create a new question regarding Conda with details and error messages.

Comment: Thank you, I opened a new question, hopefully somebody knows how to solve it